# opencart error occurs in admin file

Tags: opencart

Error occurs in opencart admin file how it solve please help me

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_MODIFICATION - assumed 'DIR_MODIFICATION' in
>   /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/startup.php on line
>   72Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_MODIFICATION - assumed
>   'DIR_MODIFICATION' in
>   /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/startup.php on line
>   76Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_MODIFICATION - assumed
>   'DIR_MODIFICATION' in
>   /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/startup.php on line
>   72Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_MODIFICATION - assumed
>   'DIR_MODIFICATION' in
>   /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/startup.php on line
>   76Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_MODIFICATION - assumed
>   'DIR_MODIFICATION' in
>   /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/startup.php on line
>   72Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR_MODIFICATION - assumed
>   'DIR_MODIFICATION' in
>   /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/startup.php on line 76
>       and error occurs in website Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /home/ganeshk2334/public_html/test2/system/library/cache/file.php on
>   line 59

these cart in server my cart is working in localhost but not working in server please find it and solve it.

Comment: Can we take a look at the code that caused this error?

Comment: yes the above code is error in open cart admin file

Comment: Looking at the error code is useless, the source code might lead to the correct solution.